# How to run one job at a time but all of them each hour?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have the following set of commands:

```
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Account;
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=AgreementType;
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=CFProgramLevel;
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Product;
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Customer;
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Distributor;
```

Because the command listed above is a sequence then they have to be executed in the order they appear.

What do I need to achieve?

- Run one and only one job at a time
- Respect the sequence and this mean for example: `Account` has to run first than `AgreementType`, `AgreementType` has to run before `CFProgramLevel` and so on
- Run all the sequences each hour

I was thinking in use cronjobs but I haven't a clue in how to achieve this. Could any provide me with some answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the commands in a script and schedule the script with cron:

The script `runstuff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Account
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=AgreementType
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=CFProgramLevel
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Product
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Customer
docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Distributor
```

The crontab:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/runstuff.sh
```

or,

```
@hourly /path/to/runstuff.sh
```

if your cron understands `@hourly` (check `man 5 crontab`).

This allows you to change the script (if you need to) without editing the existing cronjob. It also guarantees that the Docker invocations are executed in the correct order, and it collects all processing of the job to one single place (the script).

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the job once every hour, and combine in the launch, all your scripts in the order of your choice

For that, you need to do the job at 0 minute, every hour, every day, every month, every day of the week, wich means this, in crontab syntax:

```
0 * * * * docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Account;docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=AgreementType;docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=CFProgramLevel;docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Product;docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Customer;docker exec -u www-data bin/console api:execute --object=Distributor;
```

So, you need to enter the previous code in your crontab table, just type `crontab -e` in your terminal, and copy the previous code